# What is the difference between the boost debug and release variants?

Tags: c++, boost

When installing boost via `./b2 install`, it's possible to use the flags `--variant=debug` or `--variant=release`. What are the differences between these variants? Does it impact compiler optimizer flags, asserts, the code itself, or something else?

Comment: Simple when you debugging your project you will be able step into boost code and see its code when it is build in debug mode. Trade of is that it is slower. Yes this impacts optimizer (it is disabled) asserts (are enabled). You should use debug only in development stage. When deploying application you should use release version (both of boost and your application).

Comment: The Boost documentation is a bit annoying in that it talks about it, but does not explain the differences.  Unless that's buried somewhere, and I didn't find the secret link. https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/tools/build/doc/html/index.html

Comment: When using msvc debug mode has some incompatibility with release mode with the default settings enabled because of the additional checks that are added to aide debugging and detect corruptions. It's not usually safe to mix debug and release using this compiler.